# Server error when copying ASP.NET code to another host

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Sorry for the simple question.

I have moved a site to a host by simply copying the code but even the first login page fails if I include the following :-

1. In Web.config file..if I add the following

or...

2. Aspx page..if I include a reference to a class file ( which does exist in the app_code directory )

   Sign In <%If clsGeneral.str(Request("timeout")) = "t" Then Response.Write(" - YOUR SESSION EXPIRED")%>

I get the error...

Server Error in '/' Application.

Runtime Error

Description: An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons). It could, however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server machine.

etc...

Comment: In addition to copying the files, you have to configure IIS, e.g. create an application for the virtual directory.  Did you do any of that?

Comment: Turn off the custom error and see what the exception is.

Comment: The directions explain what you need to do in order to see the reason for the error. If you get an error page, it pays to *read the information*.

Comment: Hopefully your application logs all exceptions? In that case, you can easily check the logs. If not, turn off the custom errors temporarily and see what's really going on.

Answer (score 0):

Copying an application from one host to another is only simple in the file copy.  There are a number of issues that may arise from the application running on the "new" server.  For example, is the server running the same version of IIS?  Is IIS configured properly for this application?  Etc ... to see what error the application is throwing, inspect the Application Log in the event viewer on the server.  This will give you some hint as to what the issue is. Without that information, there's really no place you can start, except maybe turning off the custom error or error suppression to see the error details in the browser.  But I would recommend that you inspect the Application event log on the server.